# A way to archive text files/source code

Tags: file-management, html, plain-text, archiving, code-review

As a programmer, I would like a way to archive code and other miscellaneous text-based files. I'm familiar with version control(Git, Hg, and SVN) but I am wondering if there is something more suited to archiving and accessing the files.

- Versioning is not necessary
- Preferably a good interface.
- Win/Linux, or a server interface
- Search is pretty much a priority
- Easy export would be great

Comment: What is the required price range?

Comment: No explicit price range. If it is worth buying, then it is worth buying.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Source Code Library](http://www.highdots.com/source-code-library). It's a code editor and document manager with version control. Features include:

- Version history
- Office 2007-like interface
- Runs on Windows
- Search and filter functions, with regex support
- Tools for import and export between the library and hard drive
- [Other features](http://www.highdots.com/source-code-library)

The software has a 30 day trial period, and the full version costs 69.99€

Comment: This looks good. Being portable is impressive.